# I'm having an issue with my ability to connect to WiFi

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I've been having several other issues with my PC that have either been resolved or I've figured out a path to resolve it.

However, when I turned on my PC today, I noticed my ability to access wireless networks no longer functioned, as if I didn't have a WiFi card installed.

I opened command prompt and ran the command `ping` and received back:

"Unable to contact IP driver. General Failure."

What does this mean? Is this an issue with my physical WiFi card itself or did something happen to the drivers?

Comment: Look in Device Manager to see if the WiFi card is working. If so replace or upgrade the Wireless Driver.

Comment: Hello, John. When I look into the device manager I see an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265, Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller and Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)

Comment: Find the Wireless Driver from the Manufacturer's website and reinstall it. Try that first.